# timer for broadcast receiver android

Tags: android, timer, broadcastreceiver

I'm developing this application were I do a scan for the reachable access points. I have to do it periodicaly only second after second.
I started to do it with a ordinary timerTask, but it didn't worked well because it is alaways creating new threads. So, I started using the handler class in android and calling a postDelayed method to schedule the scan!just like this:

```
protected void setTimer()
    {
        final long elapse = 100;
        Runnable t = new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {

        Log.i(TAG3, "startedScan"); 
        IntentFilter filter = new    IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, filter);

        wifiManager.startScan();

                if( !isComplete )
                {
                    mHandler.postDelayed( this, elapse );
                }
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed( t, elapse );
    }
```

The problem is that the scan is only running 3 times and then it never runns again..I can't find a solution!How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `isComplete` is getting set to true, so the Runnable isn't being re-scheduled. I'd suggest moving the `Runnable` out of the method, and then adding the reschedule to `wifiReceiver`s `onReceive` method.

```
Runnable t = new Runnable() {
    public void run()
    {
        Log.i(TAG3, "startedScan"); 
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, filter);
        wifiManager.startScan();
    }
};

protected void setTimer()
{
    final long elapse = 100;
    mHandler.postDelayed( t, elapse );
}
```